# Is there, somewhere, a table of graph calls with their details?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

After going through the documentation for days, I have not progressed much!
For example, you show an example on how to get the image of a user, by calling
"http://graph.facebook.com/{user-id}/picture", and you show 10 examples of that call.
In many other examples, you say:
http://graph.facebook.com/{command}?{params}
and said: the command may be "posts", "timeline", "sk" etc... but you don't explain, anywhere I have seen, WHAT all thse commands DO, nor do you explain what the parameters should be, or where we get them from!
All this leads to a very confusing documentation and a lot of guess work.
Is there, somewhere, a RESUME of all these, maybe like:
http://graph.facebook.com/
   username/
      picture => returns picture on jpeg format
   userid/
      picture => returns +icture in various formats
   other_command/
      page_id => returns ...
      timeline => returns ...
and, on each line, a link to one example...
Or just a list of all possible commands/queries grouped in one page?

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked here?

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/

It gives all the objects on the graph (far left) and for each object you can click and see the available fields and connections.

So for example if you looked at the 'user' object:

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/

You would see that the 'picture' connection is described, what it returns, and what addition parameters you can use.

You can also introspect objects to see all of the connections an object has without knowing its type ahead of time.  To get this information, add metadata=1 to the object URL, and the resulting JSON will include a metadata property that lists all the supported connections and fields for the given object. For example, you can see all the connections and fields for my user object by fetching https://graph.facebook.com/532338216?metadata=1

Finally, play around with the graph explorer.

http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/

Comment: Did this answer your question Jean?